# Toggle Read More/Read Less using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to create a read more/read less toggle using javascript and i am kind of stuck on what i am doing wrong. The code seems to have ellipsis but when i click on Read More, the data seems to be keep setting to display: none

I have created a Codepen as [well](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LwRYZJ?editors=1111)

```js
function myFunction() {
  let text = document.getElementById('overflow_text')
  let toggle = document.getElementById('toggle_text')
  console.log(text)
  console.log(toggle)
  if (text.style.display === 'none') {
    toggle.innerHTML = 'Read More'
    text.style.display = 'block'
    text.style.overflow = 'hidden'
    text.style.textOverflow = 'ellipsis'
    text.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap'
  } else {
    toggle.innerHTML = 'Read Less'
    text.style.display = 'none'
    text.style.overflow = 'visible'
    text.style.textOverflow = 'string'
    text.style.whitespace = 'normal'
  }
}
```

```css
.myClass {
  height: 150px;
}

#overflow_text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#toggle_text {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 myClass">
      <p id='overflow_text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus
        vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum.
        Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue
        eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer
        fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</p>
      <span onClick="myFunction()" id="toggle_text">Read More</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone can point out what i am doing wrong, that would help me a ton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why it doesn't work ?**

because you are setting the paragraph (`#overflow_text`) to `display: none` ...you shouldn't have used the `display` property as the condition here ... because your whole paragraph will disappear which is not what you want.

**solution:**

instead you can use`overflow` property as the condition (you can use others too except `display`) and that will work :

```js
function myFunction() {
  let text = document.getElementById('overflow_text')
  let toggle = document.getElementById('toggle_text')

  if (text.style.overflow == 'visible') {
    toggle.innerHTML = 'Read More'
    text.style.overflow = 'hidden'
    text.style.textOverflow = 'ellipsis'
    text.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap'
  } else {
    toggle.innerHTML = 'Read Less'
    text.style.overflow = 'visible'
    text.style.textOverflow = 'string'
    text.style.whiteSpace = 'normal'
  }
}
```

```css
.myClass {
  height: 150px;
  width : 500px;
}

#overflow_text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#toggle_text {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 myClass">
      <p id='overflow_text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus
        vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum.
        Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue
        eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer
        fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</p>
      <span onClick="myFunction()" id="toggle_text">Read More</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow. This seems to do it. However, how can i wrap the text in the next lines instead of having everything in the same line?

Comment: @Somethingwhatever fixed it ..its working now .. just a small syntax error ... from `text.style.whitespace ` to `text.style.whiteSpace ` (capital case S )

Comment: Thank you so much. this is perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel? use details?

```html
<article>

  <p class="short-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imper...
  </p>
  <details>
    <summary>Read more</summary>
    <p>
       Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.
    </p>
  </details>

</article>
```

Comment: the reason i am trying to avoid this way is because i am trying to hide the entire div. Not just the extra part. Especially assuming if let's say a certain data was coming through an API and i cannot hard code data in there.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your feed: 
the js now toggle the class `active`

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.toggle_text');
var content = document.querySelector('.overflow_text');

el.onclick = function() {
  content.classList.toggle('show');
  if (content.classList.contains('show')) {
    el.textContent = 'Read Less'
  } else {
    el.textContent = 'Read More'
  }
}
```

```css
.myClass {
  height: 150px;
}

.overflow_text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.show {
  text-overflow: string;
  overflow: visible;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 myClass">
      <p class='overflow_text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus
        vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum.
        Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue
        eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer
        fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</p>
      <span class="toggle_text">Read More</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: using !important is not a good practice when building larger projects.

Comment: you are right, I've modified the feed, it's not necessary the !important

Answer (score 0):

Use .onclick(). There is a lot of information available on how to go about using this selector. Try YouTube, or another stackoverflow thread by using .onclick() as a keyword in your search parameters.