# Show more/less text with responsive behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide

I am referring [this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57221454/toggle-read-more-read-less-using-javascript) The Change I want is Read More button should come at the end of the line as shown in pic

1. on load it should be only two lines with show more button in second line at the end
2. on show more it should expand and show entire text
3. on show less it should shrink back to two lines with button at the end of the line

[image]

```js
function myFunction() {
  let text = document.getElementById('overflow_text')
  let toggle = document.getElementById('toggle_text')

  if (text.style.overflow == 'visible') {
    toggle.innerHTML = '..more'
    text.style.overflow = 'hidden'
    text.style.textOverflow = 'ellipsis'
    text.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap'
  } else {
    toggle.innerHTML = 'less'
    text.style.overflow = 'visible'
    text.style.textOverflow = 'string'
    text.style.whiteSpace = 'normal'
  }
}
```

```css
.myClass {
  height: 150px;
  width : 500px;
}

#overflow_text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#toggle_text {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button_span{
    border: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 myClass">
      <p id='overflow_text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus
        vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum.
        Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue
        eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer
        fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</p>
      <span onClick="myFunction()" id="toggle_text" class="button_span">more</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Kinglish Read More should be at the end of the second line and it should be responsive. Looks like Read more is on new line

Comment: Here's a solution I made for someone else a while ago. If you find it helpful, give it an upvote : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67731253/1772933

Comment: @Kinglish Thanks for redirecting me to existing solution. I have udpated my question now. I just want to implement "more/less" button in the same line

Comment: try setting your `p` to be `display:inline-block`.. and no upvote?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest including the "..." in the button, because the text does not "know" when it has run out of space.

CSS:

```
#mainContent{
    position:relative;
    line-height:1em;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.showContent{
    height: 2em;
}
.hideContent{
    height: auto;
}
#moreButton{
    position:absolute;                 
    bottom:0;                         
    right:0;        
    cursor:pointer;
    background:white;    
    padding-left:4px;             
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="showContent" id="mainContent">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
    <span id="moreButton" onclick="showMoreLess()">...more</span>
</div>
```

...and finally JS:

```
function showMoreLess(){
    var mc = document.getElementById('mainContent');
    var btn = document.getElementById('moreButton');
    if (btn.innerHTML == '...more') {
        mc.className = 'hideContent';
        btn.innerHTML = '...less';
    } else {
        mc.className = 'showContent';
        btn.innerHTML = '...more';
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: thanks; it would have been perfect to make the button "...more" to disappear if all the text is already displayed (for a big screen for instance, or if the text is super small).